# How to Localize JSON reponse in android studio at run time

Tags: java, android, json, api, localization

I want to localize the Json response on button click in android application,is it possible to localize json response at run time?
If it is possible then how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

create a locale object:

```
Locale aLocale = new Builder().setLanguage("sr").setScript("Latn").setRegion("RS").build();
```

get Json string and set the locale:

```
public void setLocale(String lang) {



        myLocale = new Locale(lang);

        Resources res = getResources();

        DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();

        Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();

        conf.locale = myLocale;

        res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

        Intent refresh = new Intent(this, AndroidLocalize.class);

        startActivity(refresh);

    }
```

Comment: There's always a default string.xml, you can access and modify it using getResources().getString(int id)